# Diferencias entre COUNT(*) y SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *

Tags: mysql

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un **`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla;`** y **`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tabla; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`**?

Según la [API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) es más rápido SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pero según otros comentarios por Internet no es así.

Ambos cuentan el número de registros, entonces ¿dónde está la diferencia y porqué se utiliza muchísimo `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` y después otra consulta a `FOUND_ROWS()` para obtener el número de registros de una tabla?

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Antes que todo mencionar que **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** , según la documentación oficial, está deprecado y será quitado en futuras actualizaciones.

La recomendación oficial dice que es mejor ejecutar la query con LIMIT y luego utilizar separadamente **SELECT COUNT(*)** para determinar si hay registros adicionales , es decir algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE id > 100;
```

De todas formas aquí está el post que habla de ello, espero haberte ayudado, un saludo. Link: [SQL_CALC_ROUND_ROWS DEPRECATED](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=12615)

Answer (score -1):

Obtendrá el mismo resultado pero de dos maneras diferentes.

`COUNT()` es una [función agregada utilizada al seleccionar y agrupar datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

`FOUND_ROWS()` [es una función de información que se usa después de otra para obtener información sobre lo que sucedió](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Si solo necesita el número de filas utilice `COUNT()`, es más rápido.

```
select count(*) as number_of_rows from some_table where something = something group by something;
```

[Aquí puedes encontrar pruebas de velocidad](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/).

Comment: Si bien esto puede teóricamente responder a la pregunta, es preferible incluir las partes esenciales a la respuesta aquí (resumir las partes pertinentes del recurso para responder a la pregunta), y proporcionar el enlace como referencia. En el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) encontrarás [*¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: He estado leyendo el artículo, y varios de los comentarios, y no encuentro una aclaración al respecto, la mayoría y el propio artículo apuestan a que count(*) como dices es 10 veces más rápido que SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pero solo dependiendo de los casos e índices. No tengo una respuesta clara aún.